# What is the difference between definePlugin and env variables?

Tags: webpack

After a try, I found that the effect of `webpack.definePlugin` and the environment variable passed from npm scripts are the same.
Why is there a need for a definePlugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in some cases it'll be verbose or unsafe to use env variables extensively in code.

Example one: Add more logic

`NODE_ENV=production webpack ...`

With DefinePlugin, you can define

`__PRODUCTION__: process.env === 'production'`

Then in code you can use `__PRODUCTION__` instead of writing `process.env === 'production'` over and over again in code.

Example 2: Provide a fallback

`__ENV__: process.env || 'development'`

Then your using `__ENV__` other than `process.env` will give less surprise.

Also you can define other things too which is not limited env variables.

Answer (score 2):

Usually in our projects, we use new webpack.DefinePlugin to define global values that can be used globally in client side.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
       'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
       }
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    )
 }
```

Two process.env.NODE_ENV look same but actually different. 
The first one is defined in package.json. It looks like:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "NODE_ENV='production' webpack -p"
},
```

It defines NODE_ENV='production' in node server side. It can be accessed in webpack but not in client side. So in webpack.config.js we need to redefine it so that we can use it in our clien side.

Answer (score 0):

Because you might want to just set a global es6 variable without an env var, e.g. when you have an environment variable and a global with same name but different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

A typical case:

You can't use `process.env.NODE_ENV` in **client side code** directly.

Because `process` object exists in `nodejs` environment.

But, many **client side code**, especial `third-party` library.

There are some codes based on `NODE_ENV` environment variable such as `development`, like `warning`, `log` and so on.

```js
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { makeWarinig(); }
```

But in production environment, you build this kind of code in the `bundle.js` file. So, you can tell the `library` through `NODE_ENV=production`.

`webpack.DefinePlugin` will replace `process.env.NODE_ENV` statement with `development`, `production` value.